# Adding errors to custom library in Openssl

Tags: openssl

I am trying to add a custom crypto library to Openssl. I've been following the steps available on the page: https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/How_to_Integrate_a_Symmetric_Cipher.

One of the steps is to let the library add the errors, for that, I follow the instructions available at the man page: https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man3/err.html

I already fun ./config, and it generated the corresponding Makefile. Yet, when I run make errors I get the following error:

```
( b=`pwd`; set -e; cd .; \
          /usr/bin/perl util/ck_errf.pl -strict -internal; \
          /usr/bin/perl -I$b util/mkerr.pl  -internal )
Illegal config line

Makefile:2257: fail on the instructions for the ovjective 'errors'
make: **** [errors] Error 25
```

I've try that both on mac (Mac OSX Catalina 10.15.2) and in Ubuntu 16.04.
Any suggestions to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Edit: The openssl.ec file looks like this:

```
# configuration file for util/mkerr.pl

# The INPUT HEADER is scanned for declarations
# LIBNAME       INPUT HEADER                    ERROR-TABLE FILE
L ERR           NONE                            NONE
L FUNC          NONE                            NONE
L BN            include/openssl/bn.h            crypto/bn/bn_err.c
L RSA           include/openssl/rsa.h           crypto/rsa/rsa_err.c
L DH            include/openssl/dh.h            crypto/dh/dh_err.c
L EVP           include/openssl/evp.h           crypto/evp/evp_err.c
L BUF           include/openssl/buffer.h        crypto/buffer/buf_err.c
L OBJ           include/openssl/objects.h       crypto/objects/obj_err.c
L PEM           include/openssl/pem.h           crypto/pem/pem_err.c
L DSA           include/openssl/dsa.h           crypto/dsa/dsa_err.c
L X509          include/openssl/x509.h          crypto/x509/x509_err.c
L ASN1          include/openssl/asn1.h          crypto/asn1/asn1_err.c
L CONF          include/openssl/conf.h          crypto/conf/conf_err.c
L CRYPTO        include/openssl/crypto.h        crypto/cpt_err.c
L EC            include/openssl/ec.h            crypto/ec/ec_err.c
L SSL           include/openssl/ssl.h           ssl/ssl_err.c
L BIO           include/openssl/bio.h           crypto/bio/bio_err.c
L PKCS7         include/openssl/pkcs7.h         crypto/pkcs7/pkcs7err.c
L X509V3        include/openssl/x509v3.h        crypto/x509/v3err.c
L PKCS12        include/openssl/pkcs12.h        crypto/pkcs12/pk12err.c
L RAND          include/openssl/rand.h          crypto/rand/rand_err.c
L DSO           include/internal/dso.h          crypto/dso/dso_err.c
L ENGINE        include/openssl/engine.h        crypto/engine/eng_err.c
L OCSP          include/openssl/ocsp.h          crypto/ocsp/ocsp_err.c
L UI            include/openssl/ui.h            crypto/ui/ui_err.c
L COMP          include/openssl/comp.h          crypto/comp/comp_err.c
L TS            include/openssl/ts.h            crypto/ts/ts_err.c
L CMS           include/openssl/cms.h           crypto/cms/cms_err.c
L CRMF          include/openssl/crmf.h          crypto/crmf/crmf_err.c
L CMP           include/openssl/cmp.h           crypto/cmp/cmp_err.c
L CT            include/openssl/ct.h            crypto/ct/ct_err.c
L ASYNC         include/openssl/async.h         crypto/async/async_err.c
L KDF           NONE                            crypto/kdf/kdf_err.c
L SM2           include/crypto/sm2.h            crypto/sm2/sm2_err.c
L OSSL_STORE    include/openssl/store.h         crypto/store/store_err.c
L ESS           include/openssl/ess.h           crypto/ess/ess_err.c
L PROP          include/internal/property.h     crypto/property/property_err.c
L PROV          providers/common/include/prov/providercommon.h providers/common/provider_err.c
L NEWHOPE       include/openssl/newhope.h       crypto/newhope/newhope_err.c

# additional header files to be scanned for function names
L NONE          include/openssl/x509_vfy.h      NONE
L NONE          crypto/ec/ec_local.h              NONE
L NONE          crypto/cms/cms_local.h            NONE
L NONE          crypto/ct/ct_local.h             NONE
L NONE          ssl/ssl_local.h                  NONE

# SSL/TLS alerts
R SSL_R_SSLV3_ALERT_UNEXPECTED_MESSAGE          1010
R SSL_R_SSLV3_ALERT_BAD_RECORD_MAC              1020
R SSL_R_TLSV1_ALERT_DECRYPTION_FAILED           1021
R SSL_R_TLSV1_ALERT_RECORD_OVERFLOW             1022
R SSL_R_SSLV3_ALERT_DECOMPRESSION_FAILURE       1030
R SSL_R_SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE           1040
R SSL_R_SSLV3_ALERT_NO_CERTIFICATE              1041
R SSL_R_SSLV3_ALERT_BAD_CERTIFICATE             1042
R SSL_R_SSLV3_ALERT_UNSUPPORTED_CERTIFICATE     1043
R SSL_R_SSLV3_ALERT_CERTIFICATE_REVOKED         1044
R SSL_R_SSLV3_ALERT_CERTIFICATE_EXPIRED         1045
R SSL_R_SSLV3_ALERT_CERTIFICATE_UNKNOWN         1046
R SSL_R_SSLV3_ALERT_ILLEGAL_PARAMETER           1047
R SSL_R_TLSV1_ALERT_UNKNOWN_CA                  1048
R SSL_R_TLSV1_ALERT_ACCESS_DENIED               1049
R SSL_R_TLSV1_ALERT_DECODE_ERROR                1050
R SSL_R_TLSV1_ALERT_DECRYPT_ERROR               1051
R SSL_R_TLSV1_ALERT_EXPORT_RESTRICTION          1060
R SSL_R_TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION            1070
R SSL_R_TLSV1_ALERT_INSUFFICIENT_SECURITY       1071
R SSL_R_TLSV1_ALERT_INTERNAL_ERROR              1080
R SSL_R_TLSV1_ALERT_INAPPROPRIATE_FALLBACK      1086
R SSL_R_TLSV1_ALERT_USER_CANCELLED              1090
R SSL_R_TLSV1_ALERT_NO_RENEGOTIATION            1100
R SSL_R_TLSV13_ALERT_MISSING_EXTENSION          1109
R SSL_R_TLSV1_UNSUPPORTED_EXTENSION             1110
R SSL_R_TLSV1_CERTIFICATE_UNOBTAINABLE          1111
R SSL_R_TLSV1_UNRECOGNIZED_NAME                 1112
R SSL_R_TLSV1_BAD_CERTIFICATE_STATUS_RESPONSE   1113
R SSL_R_TLSV1_BAD_CERTIFICATE_HASH_VALUE        1114
R TLS1_AD_UNKNOWN_PSK_IDENTITY                  1115
R SSL_R_TLSV13_ALERT_CERTIFICATE_REQUIRED       1116
R TLS1_AD_NO_APPLICATION_PROTOCOL               1120
```

The name of the custom cipher is "NewHope", and as you can see, I added an entry at the "INPUT HEADES" section.

Comment: The error is complaining about a problem in the openssl.ec file. Did you change it? Can you show us your openssl.ec file? What  version of  OpenSSL are you making changes to?

Comment: Yes, I did modify the file, as can be seen on the edit I made on the question. I am using the latest version available on the github repository: https://github.com/openssl/openssl. Thanks.

Comment: I assume if you delete that one line again the problem goes away? The code where this error is coming from is here: https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/a9e4e3c39eb361ddfb438edb27c754947009eed6/util/mkerr.pl#L145-L172 . As you can see it runs through the file running a series of regex checks on each line. If it encounters a line which doesn't match any of the regex's then you get the error. I just tried your openssl.ec file and couldn't recreate the error. But it might be something simple in the file such as a whitespace problem that is causing the issue. For example the code I linked to...

Comment: ...skips over blank lines. But if you have a blank line with whitespace on it then you get the error you have encountered. Basically anything that causes the regex's not to match will result in that error. So you need to (1) confirm which line is causing the problem (presumably the one you added) and (2) figure out why the regex is not matching.